# Markdown is not showing up on my Django/HTML web page

Tags: django, markdown

I already converted the Markdown page, but it is not showing.

Here is how my page looks like when I try to enter to any markdown content:
[image]

VIEWS:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from markdown2 import Markdown
from . import util


def index(request):
    return render(request, "encyclopedia/index.html", {
        "entries": util.list_entries()
    })

def entry(request, entry):
    markdowner = Markdown()
    entrypage = util.get_entry(entry)
    if entrypage is None:
        return render(request, "encyclopedia/NonExisting.html", {
            "entrytitle": entry
        })
    else:
        return render(request, "encyclopedia/entry.html", {
            "entry": markdowner.convert(entrypage),
            "entrytitle": entry
        }
        )
```

URLS:

```
    from xml.etree.ElementInclude import include
from django.urls import path

from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path("", views.index, name="index"),
    path("wiki/<str:entry>/", views.entry, name="entry")
]
```

and that Edit button in the image does not work either.
[image]

MY BASE URL PATTERNS:

```
from django import views
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import include, path

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('encyclopedia.urls'))]
```

My Django code calling the markdown content:

```
    {% extends "encyclopedia/layout.html" %}

{% block title %}
    {{entrytitle}}
{% endblock %}

{% block body %}
    <a class="btn btn-outline-secondary" href="/wiki/{{ entrytitle }}/edit" role="button">Edit</a>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Your paths seem off. Where is the directory `css` referenced, I see the `str` but where in `views` are you calling a URL with it? Can you show your base urls and imports as well?

Comment: I just uploaded my question with the base urls and django content calling for the markdown content.